# SingleColumnValueFilter in HBASE giving error

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera

I am trying filters on HBase and currently stuck with `SingleColumnValueFilter`.

Here are the queries I tried :

```
scan 'hi_rate', {COLUMNS => 'cf1:RateExpirationDate', LIMIT => 10, FILTER => "SingleColumnValueFilter(=,'19068PA','cf1','RateExpirationDate')"}

scan 'hi_rate', {LIMIT => 10, FILTER => "SingleColumnValueFilter(=,'19068PA','cf1','RateExpirationDate')"}

scan 'hi_rate', {LIMIT => 10, FILTER => "SingleColumnValueFilter('cf1','RateExpirationDate',=,'19068PA')"}
```

They all give the same error :

> ERROR: Incorrect filter string SingleColumnValueFilter(=, '19068PA',
>   'cf1', 'RateExpirationDate')

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The general syntax that I follow to query on HBase table is as follows:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.CompareFilter
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.SingleColumnValueFilter
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes

scan 'table_name', {FILTER => SingleColumnValueFilter.new(Bytes.toBytes('column_family_name'), Bytes.toBytes('column_name'), CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'), Bytes.toBytes('value')) }
```

change table_name, column_family_name and column_name as per your table.

assuming

```
table_name = hi_rate 
column_family_name = cf1 
column_name = RateExpirationDate 
value = 19068PA
```

then your query will become

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.CompareFilter
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.SingleColumnValueFilter
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes

scan 'hi_rate', {FILTER => SingleColumnValueFilter.new(Bytes.toBytes('cf1'), Bytes.toBytes('RateExpirationDate'), CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'), Bytes.toBytes('19068PA')) }
```